# asp.net fileupload control duplicate uploads on refresh

Tags: asp.net

I am using file-upload control in asp.net for uploading the file, i am successfully able to upload the file on the server. Now the issue is if i reload the page the file is uploaded again on the server. How to clear the file upload control after uploading the file?
If the code is required then i will paste it.

```
        //=========== Uploaded file format ============================
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imageUploader.FileName);

        //============== Upload the file ==============================
        imageUploader.SaveAs(MapPath("~/articleimage/")+filename);

        //-------------------- Msg ----------------------------------
        showMessage("Image Uploaded Successfully");
```

Comment: Unrelated, but this is amusing: `showError("Image Uploaded Successfully");`  A successful upload is an error?

Comment: Hahah dont mind this... Its just for debugging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Successful Upload just Reload the Page Using Response.Redirect to Same Page.....

Comment: On reload it is uploading the picture again... It clears the uploadfield but have the path stored some where in cache which upload the picture automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can post your code in

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//Do your work
}
```

Comment: page loads in every refresh that is why your content uploads every refresh

Comment: Now it is not loading the picture any more.

Comment: Sure,, i do but first i get the answer

Comment: sorry i think you have done. Do you write this code in Page_Load event

Comment: I trid it, but the same responce